# How do apply SQL like on "\detail1\detail2\" (Escaping '\')?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a table `T1` with a column `details`, data column has following sample data :

```
select details from T1;

\this is detail 1\this is detail2\
\this is detail 1\this is detail2\
:this is detail 1:this is detail2:
:this is detail 1:this is detail2:
\this is detail 1\this is detail2\
```

I want to fetch only those `details` which are separated by `\`.

For that I wrote the following query :

```
select details from T1 where details like '\%\%\';
```

> But its not responding as expected, since its taking \ as escape corrector.
>
> So, its showing error of incomplete single inverted(') !

So, how to do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, you need to escape backslashes twice in LIKE statement.

```
select details from T1 where details like '\\\\%\\\\%\\\\'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “`\n`”, specify it as “`\\n`”. To search for “`\`”, specify it as “`\\\\`”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Comment: @Yugal: try escaping backslashes twice

Comment: @Yugal It's the right answer. You need to use 4 slashes \\\\ for every slash. If you run this query in some programming language (for instance in PHP), then you need 8 slashes for every slash: `mysql_query("select details from T1 where details like '\\\\\\\\%\\\\\\\\%\\\\\\\\'");`

Comment: Worked.. But I don't understand why.. to escape it twice ?

Comment: @Yugal The explanation is in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

MySql has escape character \\ for backslash (same as in C-like languages):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Answer (score -1):

Try using '\\%\\%\\' - using a backslash to escape the backslash.